# How to Set Dataset in XtraReport

Tags: oracle, dataset, devexpress, xtrareport

i'm trying to create a simple XtraReport in my web-application. 
for this, i create a DataSet Class in App_Code folder and drag Table from "Server Explorer" ToolBars in it. But this newly created DataSet Class doesn't show in XtraReport's DataSource dropdown list. Additionally, when i build the web site then lot of errors (almost 16 messages + 10 errors) occurs like these ..

"Error: **

> The type 'Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleCommand' exists in both
>   'c:\Windows\assembly\GAC_32\Oracle.DataAccess\2.112.3.0__89b483f429c47342\oracle.dataaccess.dll'
>   and 'c:\Program Files (x86)\Reference
>   Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.0\Oracle.DataAccess.dll'  c:\Users\Awaidus\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary
>   ASP.NET Files\surveybuilder\8874cc1e\a1214053\App_Code.qqrotzbv.4.cs
>
> Message   1   Could not find schema information for the element
>   'devExpress'. D:\Awaidus\Documents\visual studio
>   2012\Project\Global\SurveyBuilder\web.config  118 3   D:...\SurveyBuilder
>
> Message   2   Could not find schema information for the element
>   'themes'. D:\Awaidus\Documents\visual studio
>   2012\Project\Global\SurveyBuilder\web.config  119 4   D:...\SurveyBuilder\
>
> Message   6   Could not find schema information for the attribute
>   'customThemeAssemblies'.  D:\Awaidus\Documents\visual studio
>   2012\Project\Global\SurveyBuilder\web.config  119 67  D:...\SurveyBuilder\
>
> Message   10  Could not find schema information for the attribute
>   'enableResourceCompression'.  D:\Awaidus\Documents\visual studio
>   2012\Project\Global\SurveyBuilder\web.config  120 79  D:...\SurveyBuilder\
>
> Message   14  Could not find schema information for the attribute
>   'doctypeMode'.    D:\Awaidus\Documents\visual studio
>   2012\Project\Global\SurveyBuilder\web.config  121 33  D:...\SurveyBuilder\

etc. etc. etc. etc. etc. etc. etc. etc. etc. etc. etc. etc.

i defined the **connectionString** in **web.config** file is as follow:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="OralceConnectionString" 
         connectionString="DATA SOURCE=SOHAIB;PASSWORD=pak;PERSIST SECURITY INFO=True;USER ID=AWAIDUS" 
         providerName="Oracle.DataAccess.Client" />
    </connectionStrings>
```

and get this connection from the following "**ConnectionManager.cs**" class as following:

```
public class ConnectionManager
{
    public static OracleConnection getSohaibOracleConnection()
    {
        string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["OralceConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        OracleConnection connection = new OracleConnection(connectionString);

        connection.Open();
        return connection;
    }
}
```

It is also mentioning here that i create DataSet class outside the App_Code Folder (such as Root Folder of website or somewhere else) then these errors are gone but that DataSet class still doesn't show in XtraReport page. please help me on this. i'm very stuck on this issue. What i do to create XtraReport with DataSet class. 
Many thanxx and regards,

Awaidus

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i realized that oracle is giving two version of their Oracle Data Provider one for 2.0 framework and second for **4.0**. Whenever i drag the Table into the DataSet.xsd class then 4.0 version was inserted into my assemblies whereas i'm using 2.0 version so that's why compiler complain me with lot of errors. So i just removed the 2.0 version and add Oracel.DataAccess assembly version 4.0.xx.x and get solution of my issues. 
Please consider this as **answer** if you face like these error while using the Oracle. 
Thanks.